# What happens to the ASP.NET application and EF model classes when adding primary/unique key index on a table later on?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

My old application is using Entity Framework. Currently, none of the tables have a primary or unique index.

What will happen if I create the primary index now on the database table? Will it crash the application or change the model?

Comment: I believe it is created with database first approach. 
I do not see any code in global.asax. Below is only overriden method from bd context
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<MyProjectType>()
                .Property(e => e.Type)
                .IsFixedLength();


        }

Comment: Pretty sure it will just populate the values for you if you are using ints.  Otherwise you can define a default value for other types if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on how exactly you're using the models in your code and whether or not you've made any manual connections between tables inside your application by altering the EF created models. Also if you've made ANY changes inside the class models they will be overwritten when you update EF.

For the most part I would say it should be fine to add primary keys to your tables and would even suggest adding foreign keys to tables that have a reference to another table.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Teacher (
    TeacherID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE SchoolClass (
    ClassID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TeacherID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Teacher(TeacherID),
    ClassSubject varchar(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Obviously if you're updating an existing table, as you've said, you will need to use the ALTER TABLE syntax instead of CREATE. This is just an example to try and show the relationships between tables with primary and foreign keys.

Don't forget to update your EF on the app side after altering your database.